# Как передать массив в качестве аргумента java

Tags: java

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method(new Object[]{"Text", 'T', 0});
    }

    public static void method(Object... args) {
        for (Object arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg.getClass().getTypeName());
        }
    }
}
```

Рассмотирм данный код. Реузльтатом его выполнения будет

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Character
java.lang.Integer
```

Из этого делаем заключение, что, передавая массив объектов таким образом, мы определяем этот массив как набор аргументов. Но что если я хочу определить данный массив как аргумент, как мне тогда его правильно передать в `method(Object... args)`?

Comment: `method(new Object[]{new Object[]{"Text", 'T', 0}});`?

Comment: Как же нелепо это выглядит, спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
method((Object)new Object[]{"Text", 'T', 0});

// java.lang.Object[]
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал, что так получится.